# Tensor product of $Spin(2k)$ representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to find the tensor product of spinor representations of $SO(2k)$. Labels are given as

$$(n+I/2,I/2,\ldots,I/2,s)\otimes(I/2,\ldots,I/2).$$

Where $I$ and $n$ positive integers.

How can I decompose this tensor product into direct sum of IRRs?